# how can I update My values using Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

this is My addpermission function in My Controller, I need update function here to update values. how can I put update codes here. (I need update function in same addpermission function)

```
public function addPermission(Request $request, $id,  Permission $permission)
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
            'status'   => 'required'


        ]);

        $permission = new Permission;

        $permission->status = $request->input('status');
        $permission->project_id       = $id;
        $permission->collaborator_id =  $request->input('cid');
        $permission->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('info','Permission has been added to your Collaborator successfully');
}
```

**updated**
i change code as following

```
public function addPermission(Request $request, $id, $permission = null)//, Permission $permission)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
    'status'   => 'required'
  ]);

  if(is_null($permission)) {
    $permission = new Permission;
    $msg = 'Permission has been added to your Collaborator successfully';
  } else {
    $permission = Permission::findOrFail($permission,['id'])->id;
    $msg = 'Permission updated successfully';
  }

  $permission->status = $request->input('status');
  $permission->project_id       = $id;
  $permission->collaborator_id =  $request->input('cid');
  $permission->save();
  return redirect()->back()->with('info', $msg);
```

data insert go successfully. but update not success when I click button to update it is insert as new record to DB.

My table name is permission and have these columns

```
id (autoincrement)
status
project_id
collaborator_id
```

how can fix this

**new updated**

ok this is My form

```
form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.collaborators.permission', $project->id) }}">
                        <!--<div id="cid" name="cid">{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->id}}</div>-->
                    <input type="hidden" id="cid" name="cid" value="{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->id }}" />
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('status') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="status" class="control-label">Choose Permission</label>
                    <select name="status" id="status">
                    <option value="">Choose a status</option>
                    <option value="3">View Only</option>
                    <option value="2">Edit Tasks</option>
                    <option value="1">Admin</option>
                    </select>
                    @if ($errors->has('status'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('status') }}</span>
                    @endif
                    </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
                      </div>
                      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller can be written as:

```
public function addPermission(Request $request, $project_id, $permission_id = null)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
    'status'   => 'required'
  ]);

  if(is_null($permission_id)) {
    $permission = new Permission;
    $msg = 'Permission has been added to your Collaborator successfully';
  } else {
    $permission = Permission::find($permission_id);
    $msg = 'Permission updated successfully';
  }

  $permission->status = $request->input('status');
  $permission->project_id       = $id;
  $permission->collaborator_id =  $request->input('cid');
  $permission->save();
  return redirect()->back()->with('info', $msg);
}
```

So your route can be as:

For add

```
/project/{project_id}/permission
```

For update

```
/project/{project_id}/permission/{permission_id}
```

**Update**

Assuming you will have a `$permission` variable in the view when form is opened as edit, then you can write your form action as:

```
<form class="form-vertical" 
            role="form" 
            method="post" 
            action="{{ isset($permission) ? route('projects.collaborators.permission', ['project_id' => project->id, 'permission_id' => $permission->id]) : route('projects.collaborators.permission', ['project_id' => project->id]) }}">
```

And your route will be as:

```
Route::post('projects/{project_id}/permission/{permission_id‌​?}', [ 'uses' => 'ProjectCollaboratorsController@addPermission', 'as' => 'projects.collaborators.permission',]);
```

Comment: your add function is working but update is not working it is generated follwing error **Missing required parameters for [Route: projects.collaborators.permission] [URI: projects/{project_id}/permission/{permission_id}].**  My edit routes is **Route::post('projects/{project_id}/permission/{permission_id}', [
    'uses' => 'ProjectCollaboratorsController@addPermission',
    'as'   => 'projects.collaborators.permission',]);**

Comment: My full error masseage is **Missing required parameters for [Route: projects.collaborators.permission] [URI: projects/{project_id}/permission/{permission_id}]. (View: C:\Users\FFr\Desktop\c\resources\views\collaborators\form.blade.php) (View: C:\Users\Nalaka\Desktop\c\resources\views\collaborators\form.blade.php)**  and my permission add form action is **<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.collaborators.permission', $project->id) }}">**

Comment: It's throwing error because your edit route requires two ids `project_id` and `permission_id‌`, whereas in your form you are passing only `project_id` but not `permission_id‌`.

Comment: oh..really? how can I fix this. can you give me code example. it is really help

Comment: same form. I would like add and edit same form. same button

Comment: OK.. so how you have planned to pass the `permission_id` in edit case?

Comment: iCode it is the problem? I am little bit confused? how can I do this I need help this

Comment: Can you shoe the code how do you auto populate the form in case of edit?